# What are equivalent parametric equations?

Tags: soft-question, diophantine-equations, elementary-functions

What are equivalent parametric equations? Is there a fast method to prove that 2 parametric equations are non-equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unit Circle:** $~(\cos t,\sin t)$, or $(\sin t,\cos t)$, or $\Big(t,\pm\sqrt{1-t^2}\Big)$, or $\bigg(\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}~,~\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\bigg)$, etc.

What do all these various parameterizations of the same geometric shape have in common ?

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad x^2(t)+y^2(t)=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your input. That is a great example but not as much a good definition. I know intuitively what they imply but I cannot define them. What about a short method to prove the non equivalence of 2 equations or expression?

Comment: They are equivalent if the two parameterizations fulfill the same equation $($in this case, $x^2+y^2=1)$, and “swipe” over the same domain for both *x* and *y*.

Comment: What about choosing any solution trivial or not that does not satisfy both?

Comment: If $x_1(t)$ relates to $y_1(t)$ in a different manner than $x_2(t)$ relates to $y_2(t)$, then we are dealing with two different shapes. If $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ etc. do not cover the same domain, then we are dealing with shapes which overlap, but are not identical.